# Sort and list by row value in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I created a df by reading a csv file containing two fields "word" and "TAG".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Book2.csv")
print df

Output
       WORD    TAG
0     This     DET
1       is    VERB
2        a     DET
3    sample   NOUN
4  sentence   NOUN
5        to   PART
6     check   VERB
7      NLP   PROPN
8        in    ADP
9    python   NOUN
```

I want to extract all nouns and verbs and similarly other tags and corresponding words and create a new df.

Expected output:

```
NOUN           VERB
Sample          is
sentence        check
python
```

I am New to pandas. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `groupby`

```
df.groupby('TAG').WORD.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T
Out[221]: 
TAG  ADP   DET      NOUN PART PROPN   VERB
0     in  This    sample   to   NLP     is
1    NaN     a  sentence  NaN   NaN  check
2    NaN   NaN    python  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

If you want to 'remove' NaN

```
df.groupby('TAG').WORD.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T.fillna('')
Out[222]: 
TAG ADP   DET      NOUN PART PROPN   VERB
0    in  This    sample   to   NLP     is
1           a  sentence             check
2                python
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to remove NaN. Does pandas create NaN to retain column and row integrity?

Comment: @Programmer_nltk we can not remove NaN (since will remove the entire row or column )we can fillna by ''.

Comment: Once more thanks for the help. Very much appreciated. Up-voting answer.

Comment: @Programmer_nltk Yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: A small add-on- How to use drop_duplicates across the  columns to return only unique values in the list? I think, this question conclusively solves the problem in hand.

Comment: @Programmer_nltk `df.groupby('TAG').WORD.apply(lambda x :list(set(x.tolist()))).apply(pd.Series).T`